# Linear Regression fill_between with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm currently performing a linear regression on my data with the following code (from the stats models.api):

```
import statsmodels.api
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import summary_table

X = statsmodels.api.add_constant(log_sSFR_dAGN)
res = statsmodels.api.OLS(Dn4000_dAGN, X).fit()

xlin = numpy.linspace(-15,-6, num=1000)

st, data, ss2 = summary_table(res, alpha=0.05)
fittedvalues = data[:,2]
predict_mean_se  = data[:,3]
predict_mean_ci_low, predict_mean_ci_upp = data[:,4:6].T
predict_ci_low, predict_ci_upp = data[:,6:8].T
```

Now what I have done to plot this with my data is the following:

```
pyplot_left.plot(X, fittedvalues, 'k-', label='OLS')
pyplot_left.plot(X, predict_ci_low, 'k--')
pyplot_left.plot(X, predict_ci_upp, 'k--')
pyplot_left.plot(X, predict_mean_ci_low, 'k:')
pyplot_left.plot(X, predict_mean_ci_upp, 'k:')
pyplot_left.set_xlim([-14,-8])
pyplot_left.fill_between(log_sSFR_dAGN, predict_mean_ci_low, predict_mean_ci_upp, facecolor='grey', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='none')
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

I'm sure many of you will now know what I want to fix. I would like both the regression lines of the lower and upper confines to go from say -14 to -6 covering the full range of my data as well as to have the grey shaded area (i.e., `fill_between(log_sSFR_dAGN, predict_mean_ci_low, predict_mean_ci_upp, facecolor='grey', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='none')`) to also to cover the full range of my chosen x axis values.

I have attempted a `np.linspace` method but I have received the following errors for a few methods that have worked for me previously.

Method 1 error:

```
ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible
```

Method 2 error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Any solutions or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your data sorted by `log_sSFR_dAGN`? The fittedvalues and the confidence intervals are ordered in the original sequence of the data (by rows). If your data is not sorted by increasing `log_sSFR_dAGN`, then your arrays in fill between will not have a consistent ordering.

Comment: My data is a numpy array for which I've used x,y=np.genfromtxt(data.csv, delimiter=',', unpack=True).

Comment: That only means you get the ordering of the data as it is in the csv file. You still need to check or use argsort to rearrange your data.

Comment: So why would sorting the data fix the issue I'm having?